# Ionic: Getting Error Code 3 when uploading image using ng-cordova fileTransfer and Camera plugin

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am getting "Code 3" (connection refused) error when trying to upload an image file from my ionic app to remote server using FileTransfer plugin.

I used the camera plugin and have the captured image moved to permanent storage

```
$scope.selectPicture = function(sourceType) {
    var options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
        var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        //Create a new name for the photo
        var d = new Date(),
        n = d.getTime(),
        newFileName =  n + ".jpg";

        localStorage.setItem('checklist',newFileName);
        var namePath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          // Move the file to permanent storage
          $cordovaFile.moveFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success){
            $scope.image = newFileName;
            localStorage.setItem('checklist',newFileName);
          }, function(error){
            $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);

          });
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
};
```

then I upload the image using the FileTransfer plugin

```
$scope.reportSending = function(){
    $scope.report_no = localStorage.getItem('reportNumber');
    $scope.imageLoc = localStorage.getItem('checklist');

    var server = "http://localhost/api/api/public/api/sendreport",

    filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + $scope.imageLoc;

    var date = new Date();

    var options = {
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: $scope.imageLoc,
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        params : {
            report_no : $scope.report_no
        }
    };

    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath, options).then(function(result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.response));

    }, function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }, function (progress) {
        // constant progress updates
    });

};
```

when I execute the `reportSending()` function it returns an error it says:

```
ERROR: {"code":3,"source":"file:///data/user/0/com.ionicframework.appnew343084/files/1483519701226.jpg","target":"http://localhost/api/api/public/api/sendreport","http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":"Connection refused"}
```

it says "connection refused" in the exception but when I try the API in postman I can successfully upload a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching tons of forums I found out that my problem was very simple..

changing the API url fixed the issue.

from

```
var server = "http://localhost/api/api/public/api/sendreport",
```

to

```
var server = "http://192.168.1.17/api/api/public/api/sendreport";
```

instead of using localhost I pointed the URL to my local server's IP
and I also noticed that I used comma `,` instead of semi-colon at the end of my variable declaration for the API.

now everything works as it should.